# nginx + php + remote fast cgi server

Tags: php, nginx

how to use nginx with php fast-cgi server run on other pc, my nginx server run on localhost then i have php fast-cgi server on my second pc, how to connect it each other. my nginx.conf like this:

```
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    set_real_ip_from   192.168.10.2;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
        return 404;
    }

    fastcgi_pass 192.168.10.2:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $http_x_real_ip;
    include fastcgi_params;
    autoindex on;
    root   html;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
}
```

Comment: Please give more information about you local and remote pc, like ip or listening port etc..

Comment: nginx listen on port 80 (localhost/192.168.10.3:80/0.0.0.0:80), PHP-FPM listen on 192.168.10.2:9000